# OpenID, MashSSL... multiparty web services anyone?

Tags: architecture, openid

I've got a request from a customer which I can't get a clear answer/solution for and was wondering if anyone can "bring some light" to me on this.
The customer has to integrate some web ecommerce sites into a generic portal (due to some acquisitions the company has made) and, for the time being, they don't want (can't?) take on the effort and budget needed to re-do each and every site on the small companies into a "one only" web portal that can offer the whole services' range. So, what he's asked us for is a way to integrate all the small companies web services (for example, a simple ecommerce system with payment) into the greater "portal site", but in a "transparent" way that however can let the great portal know (track) that a transaction was completed on a "minor" sub site. The problem is that as of now they can't access that information directly or integrate it automatically.

Let me use an example to make it clear (just reading the above paragraph is not clear enough, I'm afraid):

1. User A visits Major Portal (MP).
2. User A authenticates in MP
3. User A browses through MP. Finds a product she's interesed in and
   clicks a link.
4. Link opens Small Portal (SP) on another browser page or the same,
   that doesn't matter.
5. User A checks information and decides to purchase the service/good
   on SP.
6. User A fills in the info requires, and purchases on SP.
7. SP performs the online transaction with its payment method
   (Visa, Paypal, etc.)
8. SP delivers the service/good to User A.
9. MP gets notification of the purchase by User A on SP, and its
   value.

(9 is the tricky part!)

My question is: is there a way to make this work with minimal/no impact on SP's code/website setup? I've checked info on OpenID, MashSSL,... but I can't really see clearly if this can be done. Or how. Any info (or pointer to) will be very much welcomed, as I'm getting lost amongst all that! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either OpenID or MashSSL are going to help you here. You are facing a classical application integration problem with classical suite of solutions. Do your MP and SP support messaging queues? If yes, then in step 9, SP notifies MP by sending a message on one of MP queues. Most likely they don't support queues but they sit on top of some databases. You might end up with a solution where SP updates MP database (directly or via a web service) in step 9, and MP have an internal process/loop monitoring that table an acting appropriately when new records come.

http://www.eaipatterns.com/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647309.aspx

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enterprise_application_integration

Comment: Thanks Yuri! Yep, EAI definitely would help here. Problem is setting it up correctly on each and every "SP" might be difficult. That's why we were looking for something app-level to place on top of the existing software solutions. It's an option we might have to consider though :)